# Callback function of calendar not fired

Tags: reactjs, redux, calendar

I'm trying to include [react-calendar-multiday](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-calendar-multiday) in my react-redux project.
In my component:

```
 export default class AppointmentSettingsComponent extends React.Component{
     constructor(props){
         super(props)
         this.onCalenderDaysChange = this.onCalenderDaysChange.bind(this)
         this.state = {
            responseError: null
         }
     }

   onCalenderDaysChange() {
             console.log('selected day change')
    }

   //staff

       renderSettings(){
         const {fields} = this.state
         return(
             <div>
                 <FormGroupComponent>
                     <FormControlComponent
                     label={<FormattedMessage id="official_off_days"/>}    
                        fieldId='offDays'
                        value={fields.offDays}
                        errorMessage={this.getError(fields.offDays)}
                        colSize={[2, 4]}
                        >
                        <Calendar
                            isMultiple={true}
                            onChange={this.onCalenderDaysChange}
                            year={(new Date()).getFullYear()}
                            month={(new Date()).getMonth() + 1}/>
                    </FormControlComponent>
                 </FormGroupComponent>
             </div>
         )
     }  

  //staff
}
```

I want at first to make sure the callback is fired, I will catch the list of selected days later. My current problem is that the callback is not fired.

The callback is **onCalenderDaysChange**

Comment: What is the name of callback? How can we help without knowing the name of callback

Comment: I added on more detail, obviously is `onChange`